# Effect of quantum tunnelling on chemical reactions at very low temperature

Tags: quantum-chemistry, temperature

Can anybody give me a schematic representation of how quantum tunneling allows chemical reactions to occur at very low temperatures like in the interstellar medium.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? Do you understand how quantum tunneling works?

Comment: Yes I do. But now Scientists are thinking only quantum tunnelling can say how molecules are formed in ISM at a very low temperature...

Comment: I am aware of that but what part of it do you not understand?

Comment: Sir, actually I can't visualize this process. I am unable to imagine it. For example if you say about activation energy, I could imagine this process how bonds are breaking and making at that energy level. But in this case I only know the mathematical explanation in which I can only imagine electron has a tendency to exist across a potential barrier through a tunnel but can't understand how reactions occur through this process.